# How to load a script code only in posts?

Tags: wp-query, functions, categories

I want to load some JavaScript code only when it is posts, and not a home page or pagination! How can I do it with functions.php?

Answer (score 1):

In the active theme, functions.php file or in your plugin,

```
function load_scripts() {
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        // Load the Javascript
        wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```

Comment: thanks but how cn i load my own code? Is 'load_scripts' a file?

Comment: wp_enqueue_script( 'unique-name', 'path/to/your/javascript/file', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

this will load the JS file also add jquery support [if not need to remove the jquery from array] and will appear in footer